# No new Jenkins logs being written

Tags: logging, jenkins

I just noticed my Jenkins last wrote jenkins.log in /var/log/jenkins for more than 6 months ago.

This is from my Jenkins config:

```
# log location.  this may be a syslog facility.priority
JENKINS_LOG=/var/log/$NAME/$NAME.log
#JENKINS_LOG=daemon.info
```

So why no new logs being written there? Files and directory permission for this log location is the same as freshly new installed Jenkins.

Thanks!

Comment: Are you sure `$NAME` is defined? When did you last start it? What happens if you make the line explicit, without variables?

Comment: @Sven It's the same config as freshly installed Jenkins. Last started 4 hours ago. Not planning to make the line explicit yet since it's a Prod environment.